# How can I tell if my <List> is being used by my program?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

While using Visual Studio 2013, how can I tell if my list is being used and populated? My list of friend below:

```
    List<Friend> myFriend = new List<Friend>(); //instantiate new friend list
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Friend f = new Friend()
        {               
            Name = txtName.Text,
            Location = new Address()
            {
            Street = txtAddress.Text, 
            City = txtCity.Text,
            State = txtState.Text,
            PostalCode = txtPostal.Text     
            }
        };                            

        lstContacts.Items.Add(f);//Add person to address book
        Clear();
    }
```

Comment: There is something in Visual Studio called debugging, try that.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: You don't even _reference_ `myFriend`. It won't be magically populated, so, no.

Comment: Your variable `myFriend` (which, by the way, should be plural) is not used in the code you posted. Does that answer your question?

Comment: _"How can I tell if my <List> is being used by my program?"_ I can tell you: it is never used.

Comment: @ErikE It does answer it. I don't know much about lists obviously. How would I reference and use my list?

Comment: Really, you don't need to know anything about lists. You need to know about _variables_. Which, clearly, you don't.

Comment: @VishalSachdeva Can you point me to an area on where to learn about where I can find list activity in debugging?

Comment: @ScottT : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you provided does not show anything being done with `myFriend`, so no, `myFriend` is not being populated.  You're directly adding the `Friend` into the `lstContacts` control.

If you want to add it to `myFriend` as well, simply add

```
myFriend.Add(f);
```

in the same function.  Then, every time `btnSave_Click` is invoked, you'll add a new element to both the user interface and to `myFriend`.

Since you can access `lstContacts.Items` anywhere, is there any reason you even need `myFriend`?

Comment: It was a directive from my professor for whatever reason.  Thanks for the help.